# Getting RegEx Code for File Name Change

Tags: regex, autohotkey

Good Day

Please help to find the right RegEx or other code for changing file name.
Many subtitle files I have unnecessary character. I need to rename in my expectation format. Here the example

**Raw File Name**

Blue Bloods - 05x05 - Loose Lips.DIMENSION.English.HI.C.updated.Addic7ed.com

**Desired File Name**

Blue Bloods 5x05 Loose Lips

That means want remove Character

- 0 (spacebar + 0)
- (- + space bar)

.DIMENSION.English.HI.C.updated.Addic7ed.com ; remove text anything after first .

Please help me to have the RegEx or any command code for this operation so that i can use it using autohotkey or any command code.
Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Your description is incorrect: it gives `Blue Bloods -5x05 Loose Lips`, or `Blue Bloods5x05 Loose Lips` if done in reverse order.

Comment: I think Rhinemine means that he wants to remove "0" _when it is preceded by space_ (i.e., _replace_ space+"0" with space).

Comment: I don't use Windows or AutoHotKey, but if you can get any version of sed for your system, it's perfect for cleaning up pesky text data like this. It has very powerful regex support. You can also just set it up with constant sample texts going into it until you get your regex to work properly. I know cygwin supplies all the tools like this, but you can probably find a standalone sed for Windows as well. http://www.thoughtasylum.com/blog/2011/9/30/using-sed-on-windows.html

Answer (score 1):

Reading your question I assume that your generic format is

```
<strictly-alphanumeric string of arbitrary length greater 0> - <number of at least 1 digit>x<number of at least 1 digit> - <strictly-alphanumeric string of arbitrary length greater zero>.<random sequence>
```

This can be solves with the following Regex:

```
^([\w ]+) - 0*([1-9]+\d*)x(\d+) - ([\w ]+)\..*$
```

group one will contain "Blue Bloods", group two will contain "5", group three will contain "05" and group four will contain "Loose Lips".

To assemble it to the correct syntax, replace by

```
\1 \2x\3 \4
```

This has been tested in notepad++ with your example string.